# Averages and multiple table joins

Tags: sql, database, join, average

I have three tables:

```
Appliances(ID, AppType, Price)

Salespeople(EmployeeID, EmployeeName, CommRate)

Sales(EmployeeID, AppID, Qty)
```

I've left out some other columns.

I have a join for Appliances to Sales linking Appliance.ID to Sales.AppID, this lets me multiply the Sales.Qty by the Appliance.Price resulting in a Total for each sale listed next to each Sales.EmployeeID.
And a separate join for Salespeople to Sales linking EmployeeID's, which gives me the EmployeeName for each sale.

My issue is I need to multiply the Salespeople.CommRate by the Total to get the commission for each sale, average the commissions of each employee separately and list that average next to each employee.

```
EmployeeName             Average Commission
A                       N1
B                       N2
C                       N3
```

Comment: What does your query look like so far?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
SELECT  sp.EmployeeName,
        AVG(s.Qty * a.Price * sp.CommRate)
FROM    Salespeople sp  LEFT JOIN
        Appliances a    ON  sp.EmployeeID = a.EmployeeID LEFT JOIN
        Sales s ON  a.ID = s.AppID
GROUP BY    sp.EmployeeName
```

Comment: Returns invalid object name Salespeople.

Comment: That is the name of the table you provided. What database are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?